# Setting custom MariaDB max_allowed_packet value in Debian 11?

Tags: mariadb, configuration, debian

[This is more of an OS config file question, but I have had no response on Unix.SE, so I am hoping that the 'join' of DB admins and sysadmins here may result in better luck…]

Our Moodle server, running Debian 11 (bullseye), now seems to produce an "Error writing to database" message in the web browser when course admins try to manually backup some (larger) courses.

The error message links to [error/moodle/dmlwriteexception](https://docs.moodle.org/39/en/error/moodle/dmlwriteexception), which says that we may need to increase the DB server's `max_allowed_packet` setting.

The page refers to MySQL, but we are running MariaDB (v10.5.15), although I expect the issue will be similar(?).

Indeed, the MariaDB config still seems to be inside `/etc/mysql/`, but I am not sure which config file I may need to change (or whether I can add an additional "local" 'override' file in one of the `*conf.d` folders) with the amended setting.

None of

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1126 Feb 18  2022 mariadb.cnf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   24 Jun 22  2020 my.cnf -> /etc/alternatives/my.cnf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  839 Aug  3  2016 my.cnf.fallback
```

contain a default `max_allowed_packet` value.

All of these files 'include' `!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/`, and `my.cnf` and `mariadb.conf` both also 'include' `!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/` as well.

In the `*conf.d` folders, `max_allowed_packet` is referred to in the following:

```
conf.d/mysqldump.cnf:max_allowed_packet = 16M
mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf:#max_allowed_packet     = 1G
```

In MariaDB itself, when we query `show variables like 'max_allowed_packet';`, it returns `16777216` (= 16M), which seems to correspond to the issue we seem to be having with larger files (100 MB+).

I note that the value in `mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf` is commented out. If we were to add an additional conf file in that folder (I prefer not to directly edit the OS-installed config files, if possible) with a larger value, uncommented/enabled, would that be the right place/way for us to increase this setting?

Comment: Did you restart between adding the setting and checking the value?

Comment: I haven't changed anything yet, as I'm trying to work out where to actually make the change.

Comment: Some file in conf.d.  Or multiple such files -- repetition won't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Do not alter default settings without serious justifications - they effects both all applications and the server itself.

Your web application, which fails due to this setting, connects to MySQL via some access library. This connection have a lot of settings (host, user, password, default database and so on)... including such setting like "Additional commands" - the commands which are executed each time when the connection established. Add a command `SET SESSION max_allowed_packet = {needed_value};` to this setting in the application settings. And this problem should be solved.

If this new setting value will decrease the performance in another application's functions then do not alter connection settings in the app settings but adjust its properties for definite connection object in those code place where the function in question is performed.

The most particular option is to adjust the connection setting during this manual backup. Admin who backups the data should do this "by hands", he must execute the above SQL statement immediately before the backing up.

---

### Update.

In MariaDB this session setting is not dynamic.

So in MariaDB the admin may use the next method:

1. Open connection #1.
2. Set needed setting value globally by `SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = {needed_value};`.
3. Open connection #2.
4. Perform the backup using connection #2.
5. Restore previous setting value.

Comment: I know that the server side settings affect the entire DB server. I was unaware that client side settings could actually exceed the server side limits, is that definitely the case (and without a DB server restart)? 

The host is solely dedicated to Moodle, so increasing the server side settings shouldn't affect anything else (and I don't think that Moodle allows these sort of DB parameters to be set from its side?).

Comment: @dave559 *I was unaware that client side settings could actually exceed the server side limits, is that definitely the case (and without a DB server restart)?* Dynamic session settings are applied immediately in current session only. Dynamic server (global) settings are applied either immediately or for to the sessions opened after new setting applying - depends on the setting. Both types not needed in service restart but acts (are valid) until restart only except those which can be and are set as permanent. Non-dynamic settings needs in service restart for to be applied.

Comment: *increasing the server side settings shouldn't affect anything else* The setting described above must and will effect. This will increase server's memory consumption which may decrease total performance.

Comment: Sure. Our server is quite well specced so increased RAM or CPU usage should not be an issue (RAM and CPU use are both currently quite low, presumably because of the current PHP/MariaDB settings). Our Moodle installation has presumably now reached the size/usage where the MariaDB default settings are no longer sufficient.